# creating system wide vista keyboard shortcuts and macros

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

This question might not seem programming related at first, but let me explain.

I'm stuck with using a keyboard that doesn't have <kbd>home</kbd> <kbd>end</kbd> <kbd>page up</kbd> and <kbd>page down</kbd> buttons. I need those functions for programming.

So the question is: what's a good/free utility to define system wide shortcuts and macros in vista? Mapping for example "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>left arrow</kbd> to <kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>right arrow</kbd> to <kbd>end</kbd> would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoHotKey is the most configurable I know...

http://www.autohotkey.com

[EDIT]
Another neat utility is Microsoft Keyboard Layout creator

http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/msklc.mspx

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) worked out great. Here's the script I'm using:

```
#Right::End
#Left::Home 
#Up::PgUp
#Down::PgDn
#BS::Del
```

This maps "Win"+"right arrow" to "end", etc... this made the [Apple bluetooth wireless keyboard](http://www.apple.com/keyboard/) usable for programming. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this personally, but I believe the Key Transformation application will help you out:

http://softboy.net/key/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

KeyTweak

http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/